# Mocking chained method calls in Java/Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am using `Mockito` for mocking services in my current project.
I have a scenario where I need to mock chained methods in code. The chained method uses fluent design pattern. Code is as below. I could not find a solution which satisfies my requirement.

```
ProcessCall setValue = ProcessCall.url("").http(HttpMethod.GET).contentType(null).reqHeaders(null).payload(null).create();
```

I am trying to Mock the above code like below

```
   @Test
   public void ProcessPost(){
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    ProcessCall procCall= Mockito.mock(ProcessCall.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    Mockito.when(ProcessCall .url("").http(HttpMethod.GET).contentType(null).reqHeaders(null).payload(null).create()).thenReturn(??);   

}
```

Not sure what to pass in thenReturn(??) method.ProcessCall is a class with a private constructor. and it has a execute() method which I need to execute from the result of the call.
I am getting the below error:

```
  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
  when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
  For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
 Or 'a static method call on a prepared class`
 For example:
    @PrepareForTest( { StaticService.class }) 
     TestClass{
       public void testMethod(){
          PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticService.class);
         when(StaticService.say()).thenReturn(expected);
     }
   }

   Also, this error might show up because:
  1. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
  2 . inside when() you don't call static method, but class has not been prepared.
```

Can somebody help me resolve this issue. I am stuck with this issue and cannot find any proper solution on SO.

Thanks

Comment: And beyond the "use powermock for static calls"; also consider "not using static calls, thus not needing powermock". If you have a choice, go for option 2 here; and always!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the exception says most about the solution.. as you are mocking a static method, then it is advisable to use PowerMockito (you will need to add proper dependency) and then in you test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { ProcessCall.class }) 
public class MyTest{

    @Test
    public void ProcessPost(){
       System.out.println("--------------------------");
       ProcessCall processCallInstance = ProcessCall.getInstance();
       ProcessCall procCall= PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProcessCall.class
                 , Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
       Mockito.when(ProcessCall .url("").http(HttpMethod.GET)
                   .contentType(null).reqHeaders(null).payload(null).create())
              .thenReturn(processCallInstance);  
       ...
       processCallInstance.execute();
       ...
}
```

As i assume `ProcessCall` is a singleton you would need to use something like `ProcessCall.getInstance();` to get an object and then mark it as the result of the deep stub calls.. and then execute whatever you need on it.

**Additionally**

If you want to mock the `execute()` method, then again you can use PowerMockito to achieve this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { ProcessCall.class }) 
public class MyTest{

    @Test
    public void ProcessPost(){
       System.out.println("--------------------------");
       ProcessCall processCallInstance = PowerMockito.mock(ProcessCall.class);
```

Comment: thanks. But unforntunately power mock does not support calling static methods. still facing the same issue but i appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to use PowerMockito.doReturn(processCallInstance).when(ProcessCall) .url("").http(HttpMethod.GET)
                   .contentType(null).reqHeaders(null).payload(null).create();